# Calculating state happens to late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to make a simple like button, which has the appropriate color, depending if it is liked or not. I try calculate this in advance (before the return) with *React.useEffect*, but it seems to calculate it afterwards... I can see it because all the hearts, are not colored, but when I do a soft reload, they change to the right color... Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
const Hart = ({subject}) => {
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
    const [hasloaded,setHasloaded] = useState(false);
    const [ownId, setOwnId] = useState('');
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [favourite, setFavourite] = useState([]);
    const favouriteId = [];
    React.useEffect(()=> {
        const constructor = async () => {
            await refreshToken();
          
          
              //favourites contains all the favorite subjects
              //This calculates the boolean to check if the subject is liked or not
              //This array is calculated with axios, and is correct
            for(let i = 0; i<favourite.length; i++) {
                if(favourite[i].id === subject.id) setLiked(true)
            }
            setHasloaded(true);
            console.log("done")
        }
        constructor();
    },[])

    if(!hasloaded) return null;
    else{
        return (
            <Pressable style= {styleSubjectList.heartIcon} onPress={() => checkFavorite()}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    name={liked ? "heart" : "heart-outline"}
                    size={20}
                    color={liked ? "red" : "white"}
                />
            </Pressable>
        );
    }
  };
  export default Hart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `constructor` is async and you are setting two states which are also async functions. Thus, the for loop which eventually triggers `setLiked` will not be finished before `sethasLoaded` is set to true. You need to synchronize both operations.

```js
const constructor = async () => {
   await refreshToken();
         
   for(let i = 0; i<favourite.length; i++) {
       if(favourite[i].id === subject.id) setLiked(true)
   }
}
constructor().then(() => setHasloaded(true)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but it still doesn't work.... Same as before...

Comment: `favourite ` is initially empty. Where do you fill it with data?

Comment: Your `favourite` state is an empty array in your current question. I have assumed that you have left the details for simplicity. Thus, of course you need to ensure that `favourite` is set before using the above.

Comment: I use an axios function to get the favorites from my backen (see next post)

Comment: Still no good result.... Same as before...

Answer (score 0):

```js
React.useEffect(()=> {
        const constructor = async () => {
            await refreshToken();

            let token = await getAccessToken();
            setToken(token);
            let id = await getFromStore("ownId");
            id = removeFirstAndLast(id)
            setOwnId(id)

            const axios = require('axios' );
            const config = {
                method: 'get',
                url: backendURL + '/userManagement/users/' + id,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(token)
                }
            };

            axios(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    setFavourite(response.data.favouriteSubjects)
                    // console.log(response.data.favouriteSubjects)
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            for(let i = 0; i<favourite.length; i++) {
                if(favourite[i].id === subject.id) setLiked(true)
            }
        }
        constructor().then(() => {
            setHasloaded(true);
            console.log("done");
        }).catch(e=>console.log(e));
    },[])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).